# Smooth sidebar toggle animation with vuejs and tailwind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm making a slide sidebar with vuejs and tailwind. It works but feels kind of sluggish. Is there a way to make it smoother ?

[working codepen example](https://codepen.io/tuturu1014/pen/oNzRXeW)

```css
.slide-enter-active {
  animation: slideIn 1s ease;
}
.slide-leave-active {
  animation: slideIn 1s ease reverse;
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0%   {max-width: 0%;}
  50%   {max-width: 50%;}
  100% {max-width: 100%}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

  <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen" class="bg-blue-200 p-5">
    <span v-if="isOpen">Open</span>
    <span v-else>Close</span>
  </button>
  <div class="flex flex-row max-w-7xl mx-auto min-h-screen">
  <transition name="slide">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-64  shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg bg-blue-200" v-if="isOpen">
      <div class="min-h-screen">sidebar</div>
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div class="flex w-full  min-h-screen bg-red-400">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `transition` instead of `animation` and target the `width` property :

```
 .slide-enter-active, .slide-leave-active {
  transition: width 1s;
}
.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to{
  width:0;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/ExgzKyj)**